# to draw html inside js file

Tags: html

I have to keep a div and inside that I have to have answers and then the div should close.Even after closing the div after the questions in the loop,The div div gets closed without the answers..
code :

```
if(a.isQuestion == "true"){
                  ansdetails="";
                  ansdiv ="";
                  $.each(a.answers, function(key, b) {
                      if(a.anstype=="select only one"){
                          ansdetails +="<div id=\"" +b.nextuid+ "\" data-link=\"Answer" +a.index+ "\"  class=\"showfirst\"><tr><th width=\"20\" height=\"40\" align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" scope=\"row\" class=\"questionnaireanswer\"><input name=\"radiobuttton\" answered=\"\" current-index=\""+a.index+"\" value=\"" +b.ansuid +"\"  data-value=\"" +b.ansuid+ "\" class=\"\" type=\"radio\">" +b.ansname+ " .</th>\
                          <td width=\"438\" height=\"40\" align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" class=\"questionnaireanswer\"> " +b.ansvalue+ "</td></tr></div>";
                      }
                      else{
                          ansdetails +=" <div id=\"Answer" +a.index+ "\"  class=\"showfirst\">\<tr>\
                          <th width=\"20\" height=\"40\" align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" scope=\"row\" class=\"questionnaireanswer\"><input name=\"chk\" current-index=\""+a.index+"\" id=\"" +b.ansuid +"\" value=\"" +b.nextuid+ "\" data-value=\"" +b.ansuid+ "\" class=\"\" type=\"checkbox\">" +b.ansname+ " .</th>\
                          <td width=\"438\" height=\"40\" align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" class=\"questionnaireanswer\"> " +b.ansvalue+ "</td></tr>";
                      }
                  });            

              }
```

RESULT :

```
<div id=/"/"></div>
<tr><td><input type=/"radio/" name="dd" value=/"/">Answer 1</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type=/"radio/" name="dd" value=/"/">Answer 2</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type=/"radio/" name="dd" value=/"/">Answer 3</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type=/"radio/" name="dd" value=/"/">Answer 4</td></tr>
```

EXPECTED RESULT :

```
<div id=/"/">
<tr><td><input type=/"radio/" name="dd" value=/"/">Answer 1</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type=/"radio/" name="dd" value=/"/">Answer 2</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type=/"radio/" name="dd" value=/"/">Answer 3</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type=/"radio/" name="dd" value=/"/">Answer 4</td></tr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A `<tr>` element cannot be a child of a `<div>` element (only table/thead/tbody/tfoot). Try generating valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Quentin, you table generation contains an error. Valid syntax is more like this :

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label><input type="radio" name="dd" value="">Answer 1</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label><input type="radio" name="dd" value="">Answer 2</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label><input type="radio" name="dd" value="">Answer 3</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Anyway, it may be easier and more readable to generate a list :

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label><input type="radio" name="dd" value="">Answer 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label><input type="radio" name="dd" value="">Answer 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label><input type="radio" name="dd" value="">Answer 3</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```